# How to get distinct values from array in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, distinct-values

I am trying to make well typed function for getting only distinct values of object's property in array. So it works like that

```js
type Employee = { work: WorkEnum; name: string };
const arg1: Employee[] = [{ name: "kornad", work: WorkEnum.Doctor}, { name: "Adam", work: WorkEnum.FrontEndDeveloper}]

const result1: WorkEnum[] = getDistinct(arg1, 'work')
const result1: string[] = getDistinct(arg1, 'name')
```

so function needs to detect possible keys for seconds argument (that I've managed to do) and type of the value (I don't know how to do this one)

Here is my function

```js
type ArrayObject<V> = {
  [key: string]: V;
};

function getDistinct<V, T extends ArrayObject<V>>(
  data: T[],
  property: keyof T
): V[] {
  const allValues = data.reduce((values: V[], current) => {
    if (current[property]) {
      values.push(current[property]);
    }
    return values;
  }, []);

  return [...new Set(allValues)];
}

const arrayOfData: { xxx: string; qwe: string | number }[] = [
  { xxx: 'asd', qwe: 43 },
  { xxx: 'asd', qwe: 'dsadas' },
];

const res = getDistinct(arrayOfData, 'xxx'); // res: unknown[], why not string[] ??????????
```

So Typescript cannot figure it out that `res` should be `string[]` instead of this I am getting here `unknown[]`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `ArrayObject` definition and function return type are not correct.

This will work:

```
function getDistinct<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T[], property: K): T[K][] {
  const allValues = data.reduce((values: T[K][], current) => {
    if (current[property]) {
      values.push(current[property]);
    }
    return values;
  }, []);

  return [...new Set(allValues)];
}

const arrayOfData: { xxx: string; qwe: string | number }[] = [
  { xxx: 'asd', qwe: 43 },
  { xxx: 'asd', qwe: 'dsadas' },
];

const res1 = getDistinct(arrayOfData, 'xxx'); // string[]
const res2 = getDistinct(arrayOfData, 'qwe'); // (string | number)[]
```

The important part is to define your property as a `keyof T`, and the return type as the type associated with that property (`T[K]`), or in this case, an array of that type (`T[K][]`).

---

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCIwM60lAHgBUAaRAaUVQA8pUwATbRAa1QE85hEiA+ACgBQiRAwCGUMQC4eAbQC6JYYgAOAJzgrUaqOxnlBAShlFZ5eQsQBvZRAS5EYgDZOAas5CpmAXlESxAHRqqAwgEKj8-ABuHl4mZhaKiBAgasFgUIaI3rzWyiIw3PwpafRQsuqa2rryWTYiDYgxTp7YASog2AAWxanp5ZVaOuy1ANz5iAC+E8FQqUjNreMik2QKhuPKs-OIsgH7YKgA7ogAyuj8zm6x2Iby49OCdmAOYmli7ADywBj+MlaIahAmS4NQwMDIUaIACOR1QIKgYIhiAAPogwCAALYAI20U0svlkygBQOoMgA5GJsAxyWRYfDEAAWADMUyUIhJwMQlOptJhcIpTDE4mw5LZgnugie9igiGC2AAjNkUOgsLhwdBLu8vj9-GRyaTyRtEAB6E2IUHg5AKaUvWXygBMyrQmBweE1bzUH2+v0k+vpRqhZsQ-EtyLRGJx2kMCiAA)

Comment: Side note: probably better to reduce immediately to a `Set`, without creating the intermediate array.

Comment: is there a way to exclude undefined from the return type?

Comment: The example you gave does not have `undefined` in the return type...

Comment: but if we have a type like that `{ xxx?: string }` and we are taking that `xxx` property is there a way to have a return type only as `string[]`?

Comment: You can exclude null and undefined using [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet),